# What does Linear Congruential mean?

Tags: terminology, random

How does one interpret the terms "Linear" and "Congruential" as in a "Linear congruential RNG"?

I am used to linearity by $f(ax)=af(x)$. This does not seem to me to hold true in this case ($\bmod$). I have no idea how to interpret the congruential part.

Comment: Note that there is more than one common use of the word "linear" in mathematics. $y=ax+b$ is linear in the sense that its graph is a straight line, even though it isn't linear in the sense of linear algebra.

Comment: Knuth has entire chapter devoted to random numbers, TAOCP, Vol. 2, Chapter 3. In 3.2 he discusses Lehmer's work and the linear congruential method.

Comment: @dbasnett Yes, I have read Knuth's work and thats partly the reason why I am asking this question. (Proud owner of the 4 (3 1/2?) volumes)

Comment: @Gerry Good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Exactly What It Says On The Tin.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ExactlyWhatItSaysOnTheTin)

Let's break it down by looking at the definition. An LCG is any PRNG that takes the form

$$x_{k+1}=(ax_k+b)\bmod M$$

where $x_0,a$ and $b$ are some integer parameters, and $M$ is a large integer only slightly below the largest representable integer on the machine.

We can see where the name comes from (which, BTW, is due to D.H. Lehmer): "linear" is due to the fact that the quantity whose remainder we are taking is the result of a linear function ($ax+b$), and "congruential", since we are performing a [congruence operation (modulo)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence_relation).